# Is it possible to create a select all checkbox in the SELECT_MULTIPLE configuration object in Looker Studio connector?

Tags: multi-select, looker-studio, connector, data-studio-custom-visuals

I want to be able to check a checkbox that will select all available options within the SELECT_MULTIPLE dropdown element during configuration of my looker studio connector.

Is it possible with the current Looker Studio connector API.
Default behavior is as in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfyyW.png)

But I have seen one connector with a select all checkbox in the search bar.
Using this reference: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/reference#legacy_1